# Node App works on localhost, not on the server (Digitalocean, express.js)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, deployment, digital-ocean

This is the first app I've tried to deploy and I've hit a wall and am losing the last of my hair.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

When I build it with the hello.js app that is in the tutorial everything works fine. When I try and switch their app for the one I've built it doesn't work. My app works great on my localhost.

This is the code I'm using to create the server and I feel like this is where the problem is happening.

bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('delivbeer:server');
var http = require('http');


var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// // var index = require('./routes/index');
// var users = require('./routes/users');

//Setup Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/delivbeer', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Setup Express Session / Passport 
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);

//Setup Connect-Flash
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());

//Routes
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I run I don't get any errors, but if I `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` when the app is running on the server I get a connection refused error.

Please Help!

Comment: `var app = require('../app');` - can you post the content of that file you're importing? Or at least the relevant sections like what you are exporting there

Comment: @PatNeedham updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem I see is that Digital Ocean tutorial is using the built-in Node `http` module, while you are attempting to use that module in addition to the `Express` library for handling your web server.

Notice how in the tutorial, `hello.js` is:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS');
console.log('Server running at http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/');
```

The argument passed to the `createServer` function is another function with arguments `req` and `res`.

In your `bin/www` code you have `var server = http.createServer(app);`

But the `app` you are passing to `createServer` is whatever is being exported from `app.js` - not a function but the full Express object (`var app = express(); ... module.exports = app;`)

I suggest following an [Express guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). From the example there:

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

You can do something similar to that in your `bin/www`. Actually, it looks like it can all be done in your `app.js` file. Instead of doing `module.exports` at the end, you can include:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
}

// copy over normalizePort function from bin/www
```

Then to start your server, just run `node app.js` from that directory.

Comment: Once I moved all the server logic out of bin/www and into app.js everything worked great. I have a deployed app now! Thanks!